# Webpack with WordPress Plugins, what's the best way?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins, webpack

I understand webpack (at least enough to get me into trouble). How could a WordPress plugin author build modular plugins (ie one plugin extends another) that utilizes webpack in the most efficient manner possible?

I would think that if I created Plugin-A using webpack and then created Plugin-B, which extends Plugin-A, also with webpack, that a certain amount of the bundled JS would be duplicated between the plugins.

It would be ideal if I could dynamically append to the webpack config from Plugin-A when Plugin-B loads.

Is there a built in method of making something like this work with webpack?

Comment: it's good question for developing in wordpress

Answer (score 1):

It's new functionality for wordpress. So, you have go though the article,

[Webpack into a WordPress theme](https://www.kirstencassidy.com/incorporting-webpack-wordpress-theme-part-1/)

And Also Learn the [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/)

Hope that you can use for your development

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Priyanka but that's not really an answer. I understand the basics of Webpack and that article is covering a simple example. I'm looking for answers on something a bit more complex.